# ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant CommonWarningsController)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am coding a Ruby on Rails app (rails 4), on an ubuntu machine.

I have created a new scaffold (model/view/controller) via `rails g scaffold common_warnings` , and it works just fine on my local machine (localhost:3000/common_warnings resolves to something appropriate), however when I upload this to my server, I get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant CommonWarningsController)
```

when trying to get mydomain.com/common_warnings.

I know that sometimes pluralization is a problem, these are the first lines of each of my controller and model files:

app/controllers/common_warnings_controller.rb

```
class CommonWarningsController < ApplicationController
```

app/models/common_warning.rb

```
class CommonWarning < ActiveRecord::Base
```

My rails app already has 30something tables in the database, I know I did have this problem a while ago but just can't work out how to fix this one.  The pluralization seems to match what I do for loan_histories_controller.rb (also a multi-word name).

The output of rake routes is the same on my local machine and on the server.  This is the relevant output:

```
rake routes | grep common

common_warnings     GET  /common_warnings(.:format)     common_warnings#index
                    POST /common_warnings(.:format)     common_warnings#create
new_common_warning  GET  /common_warnings/new(.:format) common_warnings#new
edit_common_warning GET  /common_warnings/:id/edit(.:format) common_warnings#edit
 common_warning    GET  /common_warnings/:id(.:format) common_warnings#show
                  PATCH  /common_warnings/:id(.:format) common_warnings#update
                  PUT  /common_warnings/:id(.:format)   common_warnings#update
                  DELETE /common_warnings/:id(.:format)                                      common_warnings#destroy
```

"The server" in this case is provided by AWS

This is my complete common warnings controller:

```
class CommonWarningsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_common_warning, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :signed_in_user
  before_action :admin_user


  # GET /common_warnings
  # GET /common_warnings.json
  def index
    @common_warnings = CommonWarning.all
  end

  # GET /common_warnings/1
  # GET /common_warnings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /common_warnings/new
  def new
    @new_or_edit = 'new'
    @common_warning = CommonWarning.new
  end

  # GET /common_warnings/1/edit
  def edit
    @new_or_edit = 'edit'
  end

  # POST /common_warnings
  # POST /common_warnings.json
  def create
    @common_warning = CommonWarning.new(common_warning_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @common_warning.save
        format.html { redirect_to @common_warning, notice: 'Common warning was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /common_warnings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /common_warnings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @common_warning.update(common_warning_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @common_warning, notice: 'Common warning was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /common_warnings/1
  # DELETE /common_warnings/1.json
  def destroy
    @common_warning.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to common_warnings_url }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_common_warning
      @common_warning = CommonWarning.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def common_warning_params
      params.require(:common_warning).permit(:name)
    end

    def signed_in_user
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

### Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this your personal server or a service like Heroku?

Comment: Can you post the whole controller code , you have just posted the first line .

Comment: Also, can do you a `rake routes` on your server compared to your local dev? If you add routes I believe you have to restart your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.  It was a complicated problem to do with having multiple similar but not identical rails apps running from one server.  I had forgotten to reset the connection to the schema migrations.  Thanks to those who responded!